# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sync') in react native project

Tags: android, react-native

Hi I'm upgrading my rn project from 0.59.9 to 0.61.5

I've upgraded the react-native and react package in package.json, but I found this error when trying to build by running the command `react-native run-android --variant=alphaRelease`

```bash
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sync')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sync')
    at findProject (/Users/widhi.nugraha/projects/kbru/v1/fo-apps-v1/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/config/findProject.js:67:35)
```

If I remember correctly, the react-native cli told me to unlink the packages in all of my projects. I did that, and that's when this error happens.

This is my `android/build.gradle` file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.1"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        kotlinVersion = "1.9.10"
        kotlin_version = "1.9.10" 
    }
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.9.1i0" 
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        // maven {
        //     url "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/"
        // }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4")
        // classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0")
        classpath('com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8')
        // classpath('com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0')
        // classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.1'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.1.5'
        // classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        // ADD THIS
        // maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }

        // ADD THIS
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        // maven {
        //     url "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release"
        // }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        mavenCentral()

        // Add the midtrans repository into the list of repositories
        // maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/pt-midtrans/maven" }
    }
}
        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just resolve the error by upgrading react-native to version 0.62.2 with the help of [React Native Upgrade Helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.59.9&to=0.62.2)

Answer (score 0):

> Mostly this error is coming in node side projects
> when we export the module incorrectly

**To check this error
you can check the file which is located at this path:**

```
(/Users/widhi.nugraha/projects/kbru/v1/fo-apps-v1/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/config/findProject.js:67:35)
```

**and check the type of export is correctly?**